# SQL Update в Excel - В операции должен использоваться обновляемый запрос

Tags: sql, excel, vba

Есть некоторые данные в на листе "Текущие данные" с полями `SupportStatus` и `CreatedDate`. На сколько я знаю, запросы `Update` к листу Excel поддерживаются.

Делал вот такие варианты запроса:

```sql
UPDATE [Текущие данные$] SET [SupportStatus] = 'Сервисное обслуживание' WHERE [CreatedDate] < #7/14/2020#
```

```sql
UPDATE [Текущие данные$] SET [SupportStatus] = 'Сервисное обслуживание' WHERE [CreatedDate] < DateValue('14.07.2020')
```

```sql
UPDATE [Текущие данные$] cdt SET cdt.[SupportStatus] = 'Сервисное обслуживание' WHERE cdt.[CreatedDate] < #7/14/2020#
```

и различные комбинации этих подходов. Во всех случаях получал ошибку: *В операции должен использоваться обновляемый запрос.*

На сколько я знаю, эта ошибка возникает, когда в качества источника данных для одной из секций выражения используются сложные конструкции (например подзапросы, группировки, агрегации), которые мешают определению конкретной строки источника данных. В данном случае операции выполняется в пределах одной таблицы без подобных усложнений. Что может вызывать эту ошибку?

Код самого подключения:

```vb
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\path\to\file.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1';"

sqlQuery = "UPDATE [Текущие данные$] SET [SupportStatus] = 'Сервисное обслуживание' WHERE [CreatedDate] < #7/14/2020#"

conn.Execute sqlQuery
```

**UPD:**

Запрос

```sql
UPDATE [Текущие данные$] SET [SupportStatus] = 'Сервисное обслуживание'
```

точно так же вызывает эту ошибку

Comment: А запросы выполняются на самом SQL напрямую? Попробуйте запрос написать в ячейку на листе Excel файла, а в sqlQuery= указать ссылку на эту ячейку.

Comment: Не думаю, что это даст какой-то результат. В Immediate выводится корректный запрос